# Compare attribute in nested class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I want to reuse my `User` class in my `UserViewModel` because it is too big, with too many properties.

```
public class User
{
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    /* ... many other properties */
}
```

My `UserViewModel` have the property `User` and the `ConfirmEmail` and `ConfirmPassword` properties.

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
    public User User;

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Compare("User.Email")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("User.Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

When I tryed `[Compare("Password")]` the error is:

> The property UserViewModel.Password could not be found.

And with `[Compare("User.Password")]` the error is:

> The property UserViewModel.User.Password could not be found.

There is no way to do that?

**EDIT: THE SOLUTION:**

I tryed againd the [thepirat000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391867/compare-attribute-in-nested-class#22392378) answer, but with some changes:

**UserViewModel.cs**

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
    public User User;

    public string UserEmail 
    { 
        get { return User.Email; } 
        set { User.Email = value; } 
    }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Compare("UserEmail")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
}
```

**User/Create.cshtml**

On my view instead of:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Email)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Email)
</div>

<div class="form-group pad-top">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
</div>
```

I changed `model => model.User.Email` to `model => model.UserEmail`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmail)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmail)
</div>

<div class="form-group pad-top">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
</div>
```

Now the both client side and server side are validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a duplicate: [MVC3 Compare attribute and nested object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784610/mvc3-compare-attribute-and-nested-object-properties)

A workaround could be to flat the properties into your view model, like:

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
    public User User;
    public string UserEmail { get { return User.Email; } }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Compare("UserEmail")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I already tryed this workaround too, but with this way my UserViewModel.User.Email will not be filled and will raise error on the controller method "ActionResult Create(UserViewModel user)".

Comment: I tried again with some changes and works now! We need to set the property too. Thank you for the idea.