# MVC4 Compare attribute and nested object properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, compare

Getting a model error when using MVC4 Compare attribute against a nested property.

Error is as follows `Could not find a property named PASSWORD`.

What is the correct way to use Compare for Nested Property comparison?

**User.cs**

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Mobilizations = new HashSet<Mobilization>();
    }      

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }        
}
```

**UserViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CompareAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute;

 public class userViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CONFIRM PASSWORD is required")]
    [Display(Name="CONFIRM PASSWORD")]      
    [CompareAttribute("PASSWORD",ErrorMessage="Password didnot match")]
    public string ComparePassword { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Designation> DesignationList { get; set; }
    public SelectList MenuList { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Select some menu items")]
    public string[] MenuIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(userViewModel model)
    {    

        if (ModelState.IsValid) //<= **Getting Model error here**
        {               
            _db.Entry(model.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

The View is as follows

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.PASSWORD, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label " })
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.PASSWORD, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.PASSWORD)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComparePassword, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label " })
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ComparePassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ComparePassword)
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't User.Password be in inverted commas

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
[CompareAttribute("User.Password", ErrorMessage="Password didnot match")] 
public string ComparePassword { get; set; }
```

Or, remove the User property from your ViewModel and add

```
public string Password {get; set;}

[CompareAttribute("Password", ErrorMessage="Password didnot match")] 
public string CinfirmPassword {get; set;}
```

Later you can populate your User object.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391867/compare-attribute-in-nested-class) you can find a workaround.